# Rewrite only one specific url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite one specific url.

http://example1.com should be http://example2.de .

But http://example1.com/subdir or http://sub.example1.com should remain the same.

I found the following, which successfully rewrites example1.com, but also every url which starts with example1.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Background: I want to redirect the main page of an WP-Multisite but want to make sure that I can work with the backend of wordpress and run other multisites which are subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching only http://example.com domain (without possibility to add anything before or after the example.com) use the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com(\/{0,1})){1}$
RewriteRule http://example2.de(\/{0,1}) [R=301,L]
```

That `(\/{0,1})` part is for matching both `example.com` and `example.com/` (but nothing esle) - if you do not wish to match `example.com/` remove that part from both rows.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close but you don't need to capture URI in `$1`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example2.de/ [L,R=301]
```